# How to check the progress of evaluate user policy via SQL Query?

Tags: identity, identity-management, oim, identitymanager

Is there a query to get all the users that the Evaluate User Policies job is processing or needs to process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using following query if it **does't** produce output, nothing wrong in the query. That simply means there are no policy evaluation under progress or required.

```
 select USR.USR_LOGIN, USR.USR_KEY, USR.USR_STATUS, USER_PROVISIONING_ATTRS.POLICY_EVAL_IN_PROGRESS, USER_PROVISIONING_ATTRS.POLICY_EVAL_NEEDED from user_provisioning_attrs
    left outer join usr on USER_PROVISIONING_ATTRS.USR_KEY = USR.USR_KEY
    where POLICY_EVAL_IN_PROGRESS = 1 or POLICY_EVAL_NEEDED = 1
    order by usr_login desc
```

Comment: Some assorted advice: Policy evaluations can sometimes get "stuck" with both flags set to 1. This happens in particular if the policy evaluation was in progress when the server was shut down and sometimes if a runtime exception is thrown. Additionally, disabled users are not processed by Evaluate User Policies, which can lead to problems if the number of disabled users with POLICY_EVAL_NEEDED = 1 is greater than the batch size of Evaluate User Policies.